# $p=4x^2+27y^2$,with $p$ a prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

p is a prime ,on what condition the Diophantine equation is solvable.what is it Linear expression ,for example ,$x^2+3y^2=p$, $p=3k+1$ ,$x^2+5y^2=p$ ,
$p=1,9\pmod{20}$.

Answer (score 9):

It is a rather difficult result that primes of the form $x^2 + 27y^2$ are not characterized by linear forms; this requires limitation theorems from class field theory. Already Euler conjectured that $2$ is a cubic residue modulo primes $p = 3n+1$ if and only if $p$ can be written in the form $p = x^2 + 27y^2$. This was later proved by Gauss, Jacobi and Eisenstein.
Cox has written a whole book about this problem, which I recommend to everyone interested in such problems.

In your case, you have to combine this result with the question which of $a$ or $b$ is even in $p = a^2 + 3b^2$; this can be decided by congruences.

Comment: If $p$ is an odd prime and $p=x^2+27y^2$, then $x$ is even iff $p\equiv -1 \pmod{4}$.